# Scanning a large DynamoDB Table - 1.5TB in size with 10 Billion records

Tags: database, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

### Background

I am in need to scan a quite large DynamoDB table and am looking for ways to optimize scan speed. I have tried running a simple scan query and the scan wasn't complete even after a day of running. The table is `1.5TB` in size with `10 Billion` records, with an avg record size of `0.15KB`

### Details

```
PrimaryKey: "{userId}:{barcode}"
SortKey: "{epochTimeInMillis}"
```

In our usecase, we have access to just the `userId` and we have to scan the table to find rows where the userId is in the `PrimaryKey`.

### Question

Any ideas on what I can try with the request to expedite the ScanTime? Right now, I've set 30K Read Capacity Units but while the Scan is running I only seeing around 1500 RCUs being utilized, so I don't think that's a problem.

Best,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not aware of any way to speed up a DDB Scan().. (**Edit** duh...from F_SO_K's answer use parallel scan)

Although I wouldn't expect 10 billion rows to take more than day. (**EDIT** yeah actually a day and a half to read 1.5TB in batchs of 1MB 85ms response time per batch)

If this is something you anticipate doing more than once, I'd set up a GSI with `userId` as the hash key and something else as the sort key.  Perhaps `barcode:epochTimeInMillis`

Honestly, I'd have considered `userId` as the hash key for my table...does a user really have more than one barcode?  Or is the barcode not unique to the user?

**EDIT**
I can understand not wanting to pay for a GSI that you don't need often... but storagewise, 1.5TB is only $375/mo or so (US East).  And you that assumes the entire record is replicated.  You'd want to have WCU match the table, but RCU could be 1 or 2, just bump it up if need be on the days you actually need to use it.

Comment: This is a very unique usercase where, after spending tons of time we decided to go with this as the pk. We will only be scanning the table a few times a year, so I want to avid incurring the cost of a GSI. How long would you expect a 10B row scan to take? 


I was looking into this more, the average request latency on this table while scanning right now is 85ms, and one request at most scans 1MB of data. At that rate, it looks like the scan will take 35 hours.

Comment: Yeah, that math checks out...hadn't really done it before answering...I really don't think there's anyway to speed that up.  Scan() is a very inefficient and brute force method.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can speed it up loads using parallel scan. I've done a load of testing on my own tables before and found the following rules of thumb:

A parallel scan is more efficient than a regular scan when there is more than 2MB of data to get, and seems to be optimised when the number of segments equals the number of MBs in the scan. For example a scan that evaluates 400MB of data is optimal with 400 segments.

Here is a CLI example of using a parallel scan:

```
aws dynamodb scan --table-name YOUR-TABLE --total-segments 1 --segment 0 --select COUNT
```

---

```
aws dynamodb scan --table-name YOUR-TABLE --total-segments 4 --segment 0 --select COUNT
```

Comment: That's exactly the answer what we wanted!! Our table is only 7GB but it sometimes failed by single scan but your parallel scan made it possible to complete within few minutes. Thank you so much.